Cin causes the value of a variable to change unexpectedly
So I am following this book Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++ 3rd edition and in section 2.3 Author gives the following code:
cout << "Please enter your first name and age\n";
string first_name = "???";
int age = -1;

cin >> first_name >> age;
cout << "Hello, " << first_name << " (age " << age << ")\n";


According to the book If i give the following input: 22 Carlos Then the value of variables become first_name="22" and age=-1. Age retains it's original value because cin did not succeed in putting Carlos to int variable age.
Now if I run the above code and give the same input 22 Carlos on my machine then the value of variables are first_name="22" and age=0. I tried putting the code in an online compiler and running it there, but I still get the same result. So, why does the value of age changes to 0? The full code is as follows:
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
cout << "Please enter your first name and age\n";
string first_name = "???";
int age = -1;

cin >> first_name >> age;
cout << "Hello, " << first_name << " (age " << age << ")\n";

system("pause");
return 0;
}


If cin fails, then int value is reset from c++11.

This is correct. If a string cannot be converted to number (as in the case for “Carlos”) the input stream sets the value to 0. This change was made in C++17, I think.

Here is exact dupe: Why does cin, expecting an int, change the corresponding int variable to zero in case of invalid input?

@Dúthomhas It's from C++11

Yeah, I could never remember exactly. I thought it was an annoying change, but have long since learned to simply not program code that should depend on it either way.
